# Как спрятать верхнее меню под открытое окно в Ubuntu Gnome?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

На днях довелось попробовать KDE Plasma 5.6 - там есть функция "убрать меню под открытое окно". Есть ли схожая функция в Ubuntu Gnome 16.04?

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/

Comment: Именно это искал. Спасибо!

Comment: напишите, пожалуйста, полноценный ответ.